# Nonclosed set in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a set of points $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ given by inequality: $|y| \leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. And it's argued that this set isn't closed. I don't understand why.
As I understand, this set is points under the plot of $y = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$ starting from $x = \frac{1}{\pi}$ and above the plot of $y = -\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, starting from $x = \frac{1}{\pi}$. [image]

Help me, please, to find a limit (or boundary) point of this set which is not in it.

Comment: Hint: that's a plot of $|y| \le \frac{1}{x} \sin( \frac{1}{x} )$, or something very like it.

Comment: "As I understand, this set is points under the plot of...starting from $x=1/\pi$..." That doesn't seem to follow at all from what you've asked. Perhaps you could type in the exact question as it was posed, since what you've written doesn't seem to make a lot of sense without further context.

Comment: Hint 2: From your "as I understand..." comment, I think I see where you got your (wrong) graph...but you should note that the limits of $\pm 1/\pi$ are limits on $x$ and not $y$. [I don't see where they come from, but that's a different issue, addressed by my previous comment.]

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ in your set?

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake, thanks a lot.